# Range in bash file-pattern and case-sensitivity

Tags: bash, shell

I encountered the following IMHO strange behavior in bash's file-patterns:

```
$ ls
Basic1  datei1  datie2  sdfl
$ ls [a-z]*
Basic1  datei1  datie2  sdfl
$ ls [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]*
datei1  datie2  sdfl
```

Why is the pattern with the range `[a-z]` not case-sensitive? Bug or feature?

**Note**:

1. The bash-Option `nocaseglob` is `off` (otherwise, the second pattern given above should have also been case-insensitive...):

   ```
   $ shopt nocaseglob
   nocaseglob  off
   ```
2. My bash-version:

   ```
   $ bash --version
   GNU bash, Version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
   ```

GNU bash, Version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Is there any alias set in the shell? to check whether any alias is there type alias in the propmt

Comment: Can't repro. What's your bash version?

Comment: @Mat: Version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Are you sure that `B` is really a `B` and not some funky Unicode character?

Comment: Could it have something to do with [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/120687) where collating is happening via `aAbBcCdD` etc, instead of `abcd` etc then `ABCD` etc? Thus `[a-z]` actually includes all uppercase letters except `Z`?

Comment: You are sure, you are in bash? hit `echo $BASH_VERSION` (command `bash --version` would anser same even if you are in `tcsh` or `dash` or else...

Comment: @F.Hauri: Yeah, absolutely sure, that I am in bash...

Comment: @Mat: Good idea, but `B` is really `B` and definitely not a exotiv unicode char...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want file names that start with a lower-case, use

```
ls [[:lower:]]*
```

### Edit

Answering F. Hauri's comment: [section 3.5.8.1 of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) says it all. But before we read it, let's play a little bit (YMMV): create a new scratch directory and

```
$ # Create lots of cool files
$ touch {a..z} {A..Z}
$ ls
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
$ ls [a-b]
a A b
$ # Do you get it?
$ ls [a-B]
a A b B
```

So it *seems* that bash's alphabetical order (here, on my machine, with my settings) is:

```
aAbBcCdDeE...
```

This might explain why you got your results (it seems your settings are similar to mine).

Now, go and read the [section 3.5.8.1 of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) and you'll understand that things are not as simple, that the ordering depends on the value of the environment variable `LC_COLLATE`.

So try:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C
$ ls [a-b]
a b
```

Yeah!

### Moral

If you want lower cases, don't use `[a-z]` as this will highly depend on the local settings. Instead, use `[[:lower:]]`. In the reference manual, you'll also find several other useful character classes.

### Bottom Line

So, *bug or feature*? You now have the answer `;-)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I've missed this! (But this let the question open: *Why is the pattern with the range [a-z] not case-sensitive? Bug or feature?*

Comment: @F.Hauri Thanks for your comment. I've added some explanations to my answer.

Comment: +1 more for good explanation, that answer exactly the question! Thanks!